# Unpacking a nested XML containing a list with Laravel's orchestra parser

Tags: laravel, xml-parsing

I want to parse a list of packages that contains a list of pictures. However I am able to get the first element but not the full array. The parser I'm using is Laravel's Orchestra.

The XML to be unpacked:

```
<Packages>
<Package>
  <Pictures>
    <P>20205520574081..jpg</P>
    <P>20205520574701.jpg</P>
    <P>20205520575172.jpg</P>
    <P>20205520575483.jpg</P>
    <P>20205520575955.jpg</P>
    <P>20205520576426.jpg</P>
    <P>20205520576897.jpg</P>
    <P>20205520577368.jpg</P>
    <P>20205520577989.jpg</P>
  </Pictures>
</Package>
<Package>
  <Pictures>
    <P>20205520574081..jpg</P>
    <P>20205520574701.jpg</P>
    <P>20205520575172.jpg</P>
    <P>20205520575483.jpg</P>
    <P>20205520575955.jpg</P>
    <P>20205520576426.jpg</P>
    <P>20205520576897.jpg</P>
    <P>20205520577368.jpg</P>
    <P>20205520577989.jpg</P>
  </Pictures>
</Package>
```

My extraction code:

```
$OfferSummary = $xml->parse([
        'Images' => ['uses' => 'Packages.Package.Picture[P]'],   
    ]);
```

My result:

```
 ["Images"]=>
     array(1) {
        [0]=>
           array(1) {
              ["P"]=>
              string(19) "20205520574081..jpg"
          }
        ....
 }
```

Please note that only the first element of the pictures tag is returned, and I need the entire array of elements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. My XML had a list in which every sub-node had a name attribute. In my case I found the answer here: https://github.com/orchestral/parser/blob/master/tests/Feature/DocumentTest.php#L52

In my case the solution was:

```php
 $parser = $xml->parse([
            'products' => ['uses' => 'products.product[attributes.attribute_group.value(::name=@)]'],
        ]);
```